# Error detection techniques accuracy

Tags: communication, crc, parity, hamming-code

I can't find information on the accuracy of different error detection techniques. Say if I want to be able to correct 1, 2, or 3 bit errors in 32-bit word, then I can use a modified Hamming code with 7 redundant bits.

But what about other coding techniques - I can't find any data on them. For example, what CRC polynomials will be able to detect 1 to 3 bit errors, and how many redundant bits that will require? What about other techniques?

Answer (score 2):

Each *n*-bit CRC will detect every *n*-bit **burst** error.

Otherwise, the *n*-bit CRC will detect an arbitrary error with a probability of 1 − 2<sup>−n</sup>.

For example, CRC-32 will detect every error where there are no more than 30 bits between the first flipped bit and the last flipped bit.